# how do you simplify $(n+3^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to test the series $1/(n+3^n)$ for convergence or divergence. I am trying to use the root test, but I'm stuck. How do you simplify $(n+3^n)^{1/n}$?

$ %%%$

Comment: When we are looking at a positive series and wondering about convergence, we ask ourselves not what test shall I use but how fast do the terms go to $0$.

Comment: @user192342 Why (or should I say HOW) are you using the root test? The expression you get after "How do you simplify" has a limit more than 1 but as already explained by others, the series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use comparison test:

$$0<\frac{1}{n+3^n}\le \frac{1}{3^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take the limit and not to simplify:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{n+3^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{3^n}}=\frac13<1$$
so the series is convergent.

**Remark:** the fact $n=_\infty o(3^n)$ justifies the first equality.

Comment: Undelete votes? [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/word-problem-and-formula-algebra) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013423/what-are-the-inflection-points-and-concavity-of-fx-3-cos2x-6-sinx/1013426#1013426). Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1):

$$0<\frac{1}{n+3^n} \leq\frac{1}{3^n}\\\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+3^n} < \sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(n+3^n)^{1/n} = 3(\dfrac{n}{3^n} + 1)^{1/n}$$